# VMWare guest does not automatically resize even with Tools installed

Tags: vmware-player

I'm resizing the window, but the guest does NOT automatically resize. How can I make it?

Guest OS is Windows XP, Host is Debian 6, WM is i3, and I'm using Player 5.0.2.

Comment: Can you tell us the version of VMWare Tools you're using?

Comment: The latest (9.2.3.21136)

Comment: Can you drag and drop files between the host and guest? Have you tried re-installing VMware Tools?

Comment: I haven't tried drag and drop (no GUI file manager) but I have reinstalled tools

Comment: simply set the resolution from within you windows guest

Comment: That doesn't autoresize when I resize the guest window.